# Ignorance of others when practising the teachings of the Buddha

Tags: ignorance

[Ignorance is described as not knowing about dukkha.](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/8556/what-is-ignorance-in-buddhism-and-what-are-examples-of-ignorance) If one knows dukkha and understands the cause of dukkha is starts with ignorance, how does one traverse ignorance of others?

For example, the Buddha one would imagine would have had to experience the ignorance of others. Would he have ignored it? Would he have attempted to enlighten them? Would he have empathized with them?

Comment: The Buddha saw(not experience) the ignorance of others and the potential for them to overcome it. Buddhism in the world is the result of his efforts to show them the light.

Comment: @Sankha Kulathantille - If i were to see ignorance of others like the Buddha did, would he have simply let others discover this on their own or would he have awaited for them to approach him?

Comment: You can't see ignorance of others like the Buddha. The Buddha had a special knowledge called the Asayanusaya-nana which knows the Anusayas or inclinations relating to the seat of mental disposition and kilesa that may arise of the living beings. Also the Indriyaparopartyatta-nana - which knows the maturity or otherwise, i.e.' the depth of the faculty or 'sense of knowledge', of the living beings. It happened both ways. People approached the Buddha and the Buddha also surveyed the world every morning looking for beings who had the potential to realize the Dhamma.

Comment: @Sankha Kulathantille - Are you suggesting i cannot be a Buddha if i am unable to see the ignorance of others? If the Buddha surveyed the world, you are also suggesting he had supernatural powers which seems to beget the idea that he was man not a deity.

Comment: No! Deities don't have those knowledges. There are [6 such knowledges](http://www.beyondthenet.net/buddha/sammasambuddha.html) only a Sammasambuddha can have. I'm guessing that you are coming from a belief system where special powers are reserved for angels and gods. In Buddhism, that's not the case.

Comment: @Sankha Kulathantille - I don't come from any belief system. The concept of special powers generally alludes special beings be it angels, gods, or any other. If the Buddha was man like any other, were his powers supernatural or simply observations?

Comment: In Buddhism, humans can develop their minds to attain many special powers/knowledges. But these 6 are reserved for a Sammasambuddha.

Comment: It'd be best to move the discussion to chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignorance is a personal thing, and Buddhism speaks of a specific kind of personal ignorance -- that of dukkha.

The ignorance of others is irrelevant. Yes, one tries to help others, but transcending ignorance is a matter of transcending ONE'S OWN IGNORANCE and implies nothing about the ignorance of others.  However, one might be in a better position to be patient and hence work with others.

Comment: Thanks. You mention helping others. How does one help? For example, if the person i interact with fails to or simply does not want to see the bigger picture, be it work, personal or other, what does one do?

Comment: @Motivated You have to analyze the situation and decide the best course of action -- skillful means.  Insofar as you have transcended your ignorance, you can see the situation more clearly without your personal distortions and thus are more likely to be of service.  This includes realizing if you cannot be of service.  Some people simply refuse to be helped, and you might have to acknowledge that they are a loss and move on to those you can help.

Comment: Thanks. The reason i ask is how do you move on especially if these are the people you work with, or are family.

Comment: @Motivated what do you mean by "moving on"?

Comment: Apologies for the belated reply. When i say move on, it is in relation to the comment you made i.e. "they are a loss and move on to those you can help". So if one finds that person one interacts with is unable or unwilling to see another perspective, how does one simply move away from an attempt to show this person otherwise?

Comment: @Motivated one simply lets the person be.  For instance, if I have a extremely negative friend who refuses my attempts to help him, then I'll stop trying to help him. If his negativity is starting to affect me, then I'll limit contact or even end the friendship. This is what I mean by moving on; stop trying to help, and if the person's problems are negatively impacting you, moving away from the person to the extent possible.  Compassion is good, and we want to extend our limitations, but we also have to know our limits, while trying to extend them.  Does this help?

Comment: Yes it does help. I am curious though whether the limitation can be perceived as 'running away'. For example, when faced with the inability to do more than you already have and the attempt to limit contact, moving away or possibly foregoing a relationship, what does it mean in terms of our limitations especially if these are 'family' or close friends?

Comment: Do you mind if i dropped you an email? Mine is motivatedgorilla [at] gmail DOT com